# Exposed forms distributed vertically rather than horizontally

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, drupal-views

I created a view that uses exposed filters in order to allow the user to search. The problem is that each form appears one after another and I would like to place them vertically - i.e.

--
--
-- 
[Search]

Instead of -- -- -- [Search]

How can I can achieve this using admin panel or css?
Any help will be appriciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In CSS:

```
.views-exposed-form .views-exposed-widget {
  float: none;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You will need to override the theme-functions that render that form in your theme. If you are entirely new to theming, please start reading [the official documentation](http://drupal.org/theme-guide), this [excellent ebook](http://11heavens.com/theming-Drupal) or acquire a book on Drupal theming.

The thing you are specifically looking for, is how to theme forms. http://drupal.org/node/36050 There is very little official documentation on this topic.

The concept, however, is: 
Use the [devel](http://drupal.org/project/devel) module  and the [Theme Developer](http://drupal.org/project/devel_themer) module to identify the names and/or template file namings for the form. Then override that in your theme. Add your own HTML, classes and CSS to that.